# Using i18n in nuxt plugin

Tags: vue.js, plugins, translation, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

I am using nuxt with vuetify and I defined all my validations rules (for text inputs) in a single file like this:

```js
// @/plugins/form_validations.js

export default Object.freeze({
  VALIDATIONS: {

    FIRSTNAME: [
      v => !!v || 'Firstname is required',
      v => (v && v.length >= 3) || 'Firstname must be at least 3 characters'
    ],

    // ...
})
```

I use them in my components like this:

```js
import FormValidations from '@/plugins/form_validations.js'

export default {
  data() {
   firstnameRules: FormValidations.VALIDATIONS.FIRSTNAME
  }
}
```

```html
<v-text-field
   v-model="firstname"
   :rules="firstnameRules"
/>
```

I want now to translate the text of this rules depending of the locale.

I have installed i18n following [this example](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/nuxt/nuxt.js/tree/dev/examples/i18n?from-embed) and can use it well in my components, for example like this:

```html
<v-text-field
   ref="firstname"
   v-model="firstname"
   :label="$t('firstname')"
   :rules="firstnameRules"
    required />
```

However, I'm not able to use the translation plugin directly in my file where I grouped all the rules. I have seen that with nuxt you can access the context in plugins as follow:

```js
export default ({ app, store }) => {
}
```

But I'm not able to define my constants using Object.freeze in that format.

I tried also this:

```js
import i18n from '@/plugins/i18n.js'

export default Object.freeze({
  VALIDATIONS: {
    FIRSTNAME: [
      v => !!v || i18n.t('firstname_required'),
    ],
}
```

But I got an error that function *t* is not defined. How can I access the translation plugin in my rules?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I was facing almost identical problem, here is my solution:

```js
// @/plugins/validation-rules.js

export default ({app}) => {

  let i18n = app.i18n

  // You can use `this.$rules` anywhere in the Nuxt app.
  Vue.prototype.$rules = {
    required: [v => !!v || i18n.t('required')]
  }
}
```

```html
<v-text-field
      v-model="email"
      :rules="this.$rules.required"
      label="E-mail"
      required
      ref="emailField"
></v-text-field>
```

When I change the language in my language switcher, the error message doesn't get shown in your switched language, you must re-type the erroneous email into the input field, but then the error message shows in correct language.

I'm also not sure about the `Vue.prototype`, it might be better to use [combined inject](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/plugins/#combined-inject).

Answer (score 0):

2023 update: Nuxt 3, Vee-Validate 4.x, Nuxti18n 8.0.rc-5 version:

```
import { configure, defineRule } from 'vee-validate'
import { localize } from '@vee-validate/i18n';
import * as AllRules from '@vee-validate/rules';


import en from '@vee-validate/i18n/dist/locale/en.json';
import ru from '@vee-validate/i18n/dist/locale/ru.json';


export default defineNuxtPlugin(nuxtApp => {
  const $t = nuxtApp.$i18n.t;
  Object.entries(AllRules).forEach(([id, validator]) => {
    defineRule(id, validator);
  });

  defineRule('ip', value => {
    if (!/((2(5[0-5]|[0-4]\d))|[0-1]?\d{1,2})(\.((2(5[0-5]|[0-4]\d))|[0-1]?\d{1,2})){3}/g.test(value)) {
      return $t('errors.ip_invalid');
    }
    return true;
  });

  configure({
    generateMessage: localize({
      en,
      ru,
    }),
  });

})
```

Note: i18n module should be installed and enabled in your `nuxt.config.ts`:

```
  modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/i18n',
    '@pinia/nuxt',
  ],
```

Comment: When I try this I get the error ```Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 't')```

Comment: Added a note about required i18n module for Nuxt.